# Sweet Alert window.prompt pass the value to the server

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

I have the following issue:

I want to pass the data from the input of **window.prompt sweetalert box** to the server. But i have a problem because i don't know **WHAT** is the **TYPE** of the data of a sweet alert window.prompt box.

Look below what i mean: I have the following `script`

```
function save3() {
      var id;
      var pn = 4; 
      var pososto = 5;
      var a1 = 3;
      var a2 = 2;
      var flag1 = true;

      swal("Give the User Id:", {
      input: "text",
      content: "input"
})
.then((value) => {
  //swal(`You typed: ${value}`);
  // Do stuff with value

    id = parseInt(value);
    if (id) {
        console.log("Is a number");
    } else {
        console.log("Is not a number");
    }
    return id;
}).then(id => {
    sendToServer(id);
});

function sendToServer() {
  // Implement send to server ajax request logic...
      $("#user_id").val(id)
      $("#book_id").val(a2)
      $("#game_id").val(a1)
      $("#percent_id").val(pososto)
      $("#site_id").val(pn)
     swal("nai!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "Great! The game has been saved", "success");
}
}
```

As you can see when a user clicks on a button then a window.prompt sweet alert box appears and it asks from the user to give te user id which should be only number. I tried to convert the string data to a number with the function `parseInt` but it doesn't work. The weird is that with the classic window.prompt it works me fine. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to call ParseInt("value"), the value will be undefined when not inside the .then() block of your code, try something like this instead:

```
.then((value) => {
  swal(`You typed: ${value}`);
  var a = parseInt(value);
});
```

However it seems likely the input type will be a string, so parseInt won't work, you can try doing:

```
.then((value) => {
  swal(`You typed: ${value}`);
  console.log(typeof(value))
});
```

This should return the type of value.

Hope this helps!

Lloyd

Comment: thank you for your help. Yes, it says that is a string. I did what you told me to do but i have an error. `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`

Comment: you need to do a bit of research on Block scope, the a is decalred inside the .then() block, or define your variable 'a' as var a; at the top of your .js file, and assign without the var like this, a= parseInt(value)

Comment: i did it but it doesn't worked. It doesn't appear any error message..i Can't find a solution to this..

Answer (score 0):

You might be having problem understanding how promises work. You will have access to the value of the sweet alert box inside the `then` as you did. All you logic needs to have as part of the Promise flow. You can also keep on chain then callbacks to do additional logic with your data. For example:

```
swal("Give the User Id:", {
      input: "text",
      inputPlaceholder: 'Enter your password',
      content: "input"
})
.then((value) => {
  swal(`You typed: ${value}`);
    // Do stuff with value

    const id = parseInt(value);
    if (id) {
        console.log("Is a number");
    } else {
        console.log("Is not a number");
    }
    return id;
}).then(id => {
    sendToServer(id);
});

function sendToServer() {
  // Implement send to server ajax request logic...
}
```

Comment: thank you my friend. No it's better for me to understand this thing. It works fine but in the end does not store my variables to the server. It doesn't show me an error too..do you have any other ideas? I updated my code above with your help